# Using REDIS Sets command from StackExchange.Redis

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I need to use some redis commands related to set operations. I am using StackExchange.Redis to connect to my redis server and perform the required operations. Specifically I need to perform the following operations

- Add Item to Set (SADD)
- Check Difference between two sets (SDIFF)
- Get the common elements between 2 sets (SINTER)

I am able to see SetAdd in the IDatabase interface but how can I get the SDIFF and SINTER command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the method `IDatabase.SetCombine()` for commands SDIFF, SUNION or SINTER.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the members of the set resulting from the specified operation against the given sets.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>list with members of the resulting set.</returns>
    /// <remarks>http://redis.io/commands/sunion</remarks>
    /// <remarks>http://redis.io/commands/sinter</remarks>
    /// <remarks>http://redis.io/commands/sdiff</remarks>
    RedisValue[] SetCombine(SetOperation operation, RedisKey first, RedisKey second, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None);
```

Where `SetOperation` can be `Union`, `Intersect` or `Difference`

Take a look at some of the [tests](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/29b5cc180ac560b61009ec68ea20ae1d2a0052d0/StackExchange.Redis.Tests/DatabaseWrapperTests.cs#L510)